# How to attach to DataGridCell.Selected event in behavior?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, behavior, datagridcell

I'm using the DataGridCell.Slected to do some things in my code behind.

```
<DataGrid DataGridCell.Selected="ArticlesGrid_OnSelected>
```

And in my code behind I have a method like

```
private void ArticlesGrid_OnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ....
}
```

But I want to use a Behavior instead and I don't have any idea how to attach to the event in my Behavior.

```
public class MyBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            //don't know how to attach to the event
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {

        }
}
```

For testing I used this code in my OnAttached method.

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(AssociatedType, DataGridCell.SelectedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ArticlesGrid_OnSelected));
```

But I dont know how do remove this event handler in my OnDetaching method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the behavior's target in the AssociatedObject property. So you can do something like this:

```
public class MyBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += MyEventHandler;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= MyEventHandler;
    }

    protected void MyEventHandler(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        // Do stuff
    }
 }
```

Xaml

```
<DataGrid>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:MyBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I know about the AssociatedObject but I'm not sure if your event is the same I'm using in the XAML.

Comment: That is true, it's a different event. It's not as simple to subscribe to it from the behavior because it's not on the visual tree (as opposed to the DataGrid). To do that you can you you EventTrigger http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125188/Using-EventTrigger-in-XAML-for-MVVM-No-Code-Behind

Comment: I used the EventManager to get the same event but I don't know if thats a good way (edited my first post to show it).
Would be nice to use a behavior because I want to have this behavior in some other DataGrids an a behavior is nice and easy to attach.

Comment: Then in this case EventTrigger should really be the one for you to use. As far as I know (I would love to be corrected on this) you can't subscribe to an elements routed event if it belongs to another type and just bubbles to it (unless you inherit that element and subscribe to that event from within it).
If the event would belong to DataGrid and not DataGridCell you wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it with EventTriggers :)